# How to append unique element of div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 div like
`<div id="destination" runat="server"></div>` and `<div class="errorDiv"></div>`

I write a jquery function

```
 $(document).each(function () {
            if ($("#destination").find("div").html() !== $(".errorDiv").html()) {
                $("#destination").append($(".errorDiv"));
                $("#error").append($("#destination"));
            }
        }).change();
```

In this function, if destination div contains errorDiv content skips, else append to destination. Then destination will append to another div. But, my check doesn't work . How can I append only unique elements of div? errorDiv content is produced in ASP page and this content is generic.

While page is running I catch the some error messages and I want to append something about these messages to destination div. for example; if I catch

```
 <div class="errorDiv">A</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">A</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">B</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">B</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">A</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">C</div>
```

contents I want to append only

```
 <div class="errorDiv">A</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">B</div>
 <div class="errorDiv">C</div>
```

divs to destination div.

But with my function, all divs are appended.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do, including the relevant parts of the DOM before and after? I can't see what you're trying to achieve. *(not my dv)*

Comment: Side note: There is only one `document` so calling `each` on `$(document)` makes no sense. Similarly, firing the `change` event on `document` makes ...little... sense, but if you're doing it synthetically, I suppose it could work. (I'd use my own event instead.)

Comment: @debin: Why? `html` returns a string (if we assume at least one matching element). Since both operands have the same type, `!==` and `!=` do **exactly** the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you get new `.errorDiv`s and want to add them to `#destination` only if equivalent text isn't already there.

To do that, you need to loop through the divs in `#destination`, rather than just looking at the HTML of the *first* one. See comments:

```
$(document).each(function() {   // <== Calling .each on $(document) makes no sense
    // Get an array of the currently-known errors in destination
    var errors = $("#destination div").map(function() {
        return $(this).html();
    }).get();

    // Loop through the "new" errors
    $(".errorDiv").each(function() {
        // Is the text of this error already in the destination?
        if ($.inArray($(this).html(), errors) == -1) {
            // No, add it
            $("#destination").append(this);
            $("#error").append($("#destination")); // <== This seems very strange
        }
    }
}).change();                   // <== Triggering the change event on document seems odd
```

Comment: Your answer is very clear. I understand my mistakes. Thanks a lot. Strange line is for another appending operation.

Comment: @vedat: Why would you want to *move* `#destination` based on whether there were new errors? Why do it repeatedly? Anyway, glad that helped. Side note: Probably worth removing each `.errorDiv` if it *doesn't* get moved to `#destination` (with an `else` on the `if` with the `inArray`).

Comment: it is a project requirement.I was challenging long time about this problem. When occur new error, it have to be shown upper div in page.